# Error while executing execute_async_script in Selenium in perl

Tags: javascript, perl, selenium

```
my $script = q{
    var xmlhttp;
    var args = arguments[0];
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    var url = "url";
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
my $callback = q{return arguments[0];};
my $result = $driver->execute_async_script($script,'myid',$callback);
```

I'm getting below error while executing above script.

> Error while executing command: executeAsyncScript: A script did not
>   complete before its timeout expired.: asynchronous script timeout:
>   result was not received in 0 seconds

I also tried below but still it gives the error.

```
my $callback = q{return window.setTimeout(arguments[0], 1000);};
```

and call below method before executing async script.

```
$driver->set_async_script_timeout(1000);
```

Any help will be highly appreciated?